# how can I prevent constant flickering when hovering over navigation link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a navigation where if you hover over a link you see the lower nav nav, if you click a link that lower nav menu stays active etc etc. Problem is that when I hover over top level link the hover event gets continually fired off causing serious flickering. Can anyone advise where I might be going wrong or can resolve this?

jsbin link here http://jsbin.com/ijofis/15

Answer (score 1):

Change `hover` to `mouseenter` so that your function is only executed when you enter the link.

Comment: Your css is placing the inner links over the button. Change .lower to .lower{position:absolute;top:0;left:30px; background: red;} so you can see what's happening. You need to increase the left value.

Comment: I didn't notice I was not replying to the person who asked the question, that's why I used "Your". @GGG , I see you've modified the z-index to make sure the button always shows up above the inner links, that also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use css for the hiding/unhiding:

```
li:hover ul {display:block !important;}​
```

Your code would be simplified.

```
/*
Task: The messed up GOMO navigation
*/

$(document).ready(function () {

  var lowerNav = $('.lower', '#main-nav').hide();

  $('#main-nav > li > a').on('click' , function(e){   
    if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('flag')){
      $('#main-nav > li').removeClass('flag');
      $('.lower').hide();
      $(this).parent().addClass('flag');
      $(this).next().show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});​
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/nTwKH/

---

Alternatively, this line of CSS seems to fix your current code:

```
a {text-decoration:none;color:#343434;  z-index:1; position: relative;}
```